# How do I intercept a querystring value before it reaches built-in routing code

Tags: jquery, node.js, passport.js

I am using jquery, bootstrap and html on the frontend of an app and node.js on the backend.  Additionally, I am using passport authentication with jwt tokens.  Here is the issue, take the login process for example; after the user enters their login credentials I would like to use location.href to redirect the user to a dashboard page where they can access their personal information.  The issue is that I do not have a way to send the header information with the bearer token in the request.  I found documentation that seems to suggest that I could pass the token in the querystring using the access_token parameter name.  However, since I am using routing and friendly url's this poses a problem as this is not the url pattern the routing engine is expecting.  Not to mention the effect this has on the top navigation as this would force me to have to append the token to all of the navigation href's.  Though, this seems to be a hack, but, what is a way that I could intercept the access_token before it hits the routing, perform the authentication checking and remove the access_token from the request or is there a better approach to handling this situation?

I also having another issue now where my static files are now requiring the token to be specified; how can I exclude the public folder from needing authentication?

```
route.js:
module.exports = function(app, model){
    app.use("/api/customer", require("./routes/customer")(model));
}

customer controller:
module.exports = function(model){   
    router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) { 
        …….
    });

    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
       …….
    });

    router.put('/id', function(req, res, next) {
        …….
    });

    router.delete('/id', function(req, res, next) {
        …….
    });

    return router;
};



app.js:
app.use(expressJwt({secret: process.env.AUTH_KEY,
  //credentialsRequired: false,
  getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
      return req.query.token;
    }
    return null;
  }}).unless({path: [{ url: '/forgotpassword/', methods: ['GET'] }, 
  { url: '/api/login', methods: ['POST'] },
  { url: '/login', methods: ['GET'] },
  { url: '/index', methods: ['GET'] },
  { url: '/resetpassword', methods: ['GET'] },
  { url: '/api/resetpassword', methods: ['PUT'] }]} ));
```

Comment: Can you have the server put the JWT token in a cookie that will automatically accompany all browser requests from then on?

Comment: You can intercept a query string in middleware that is registered before any of your routes.

Comment: For the cookie scenario, how would this process work?  I set the cookie in javascript before I call location.href in javascript?  Would I need to make any changes on the server side to accomodate the cookie approach?  Would there be a particular name I would have to give the cookie for the middleware to find it?

Comment: If the token is being generated on your server, you can just put the token in the cookie on the request where it's being generated.  If you must put it in the cookie on the client, you can do that too.  You give it a known cookie name (of your choosing) so you can then get it back out of the cookie later.

Comment: The issue is that if I am sending the user to another page using either location.href or clicking a link.  I need a way to send the jwt token to the server to authenticate the user.  If I append the token to the querystring using the access_token parameter, it throws off my current routing.  In the larger picture, I am trying to find a fix for this issue.

Comment: Well, you have two choices.  Put the token in the query string as a parameter or put the token in a cookie.  A query string parameter should not throw off routing because routing should be based on the path, not on the query string.  The usual place to store credentials for repeated accesses is in a cookie.  But, we can't really help you in any specific way unless you start showing us your actual code.

Comment: If I add it to the querystring, will the underlying passport systems be aware of it and manipulate it acordingly?  Also, the reason why I was saying that adding it to the querystring was causing an issue was that I seem to get a 404 error when I try to access with the querystring attached.

Comment: As best I know, passport works off a cookie, not a query string.

Comment: If your routing breaks when you add a query string parameter, then you either have really bizarre routing or you're adding the query string parameter wrong.  Since you show NO code that you tried, I have no idea which it is.